# How to use my android phone's storage as Swap memory?

Tags: android, ram, swap

I have an old laptop which has just 4 gigs of RAM, recently i started using **IntelliJ** on my laptop. The `free -m` command revealed that my memory is almost full and the SWAP space was around 70%. I don't have a SD Card with me that I can use as a swap memory.

So, my question is can i use my Android phone's free memory(almost 30 Gb) as a swap space? If so, how do i do that?

Edit: I have an Ubuntu 16.04.2 installed and my phone is Android 9.

Comment: Even if this were possible, the speed impact of accessing swap over a protocol over USB would make using such an environment painful.  Are you able to free up some space on your main disk and use `swapspace` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible.
PC accesses android phone's storage via MTP, and MTP is not a block device driver.  It's impossible for kernel to put a swap on it.